# Python - raw input not recognising mathematical processes

Tags: python-2.7, raw-input

I'm a primary teacher - I'm using python v 2.7 in ICT. I'm using a standard scheme of work provided by 3rd party company. It's been great so far. We've moved onto raw input and hit a snag, Program as follows:

```
#write input code to declare variables for number of children and number of books
children = raw_input("How many children are there?")
books = raw_input ("How many books does each child need?")
# declare ‘total’ variable from children and books
total = children*books
#print total along with text
print "You will need", total, "books"
```

Error message as follows:

```
 File "C:\Python34\ss.py", line 6, in <module>
    total = children*books
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

No matter what I do, I can't get the variables to perform any kind of mathematical operation. Any advice out there? I'd love to get my kids writing a program like this.

Comment: hint: what type does `raw_input` return?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from the types not matching up because `raw_input` returns a `str` type. It does this even if you entered in something that appeared to be a number to it. So essentially you are trying to multiply 2 strings together which doesn't make sense, hence the error you are getting. To properly deal with this you need to integers first:

```
children = int(raw_input("How many children are there?"))
books = int(raw_input ("How many books does each child need?"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw input stores the input value as a string (see here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

You need to convert it to an integer to be able to multiply.

One way to do it in two steps is this:

```
#write input code to declare variables for number of children and number of books
children = raw_input("How many children are there?")
books = raw_input ("How many books does each child need?")
children = int(children)
books = int(books)
total = children*books
#print total along with text
print "You will need", total, "books"
```

another way to do on the same line is:

`children = int(raw_input("How many children are there?"))`

I would use the second, but the first may perhaps be easier to grasp for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is as suggested by the error you're multiplying strings together... won't work

Try the following:

```
#write input code to declare variables for number of children and number of books
children = int(input("How many children are there?\n"))
books = int(input("How many books does each child need?\n"))
# declare total variable from children and books
total = children * books
#print total along with text
print("You will need", total, "books")
```

Also make sure to take off the quotation from total in the comment. Add `\n` to create a line after every question.

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_input` function returns a string, multiplying two strings together doesn't make sense.

What you want is to convert the strings to integers (since there will only ever be integer values), you can use the `int` function to do this: `total = int(children) * int(books)`

What Python is trying to tell you in the error message, is a little more complex. It comes from the fact that you *can* multiply a string with an integer but just not a string with another string.

```
>>> "a" * 4
a
```

Which is why it says that you can't multiply the sequence by a 'non-int', multiplying by an integer is the only one you can do.

**An easier way to do all of this is to use the [`input`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output) function instead**, which works in exactly the same way as `raw_input` except it automatically converts the string into the correct format (i.e text is left as a string but integers are converted to int and floating points to float)